# Is it possible for Appium to connect to an Android device on API 24 (i.e 7.0)?

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

I'm trying to use the Appium inspector on a Genymotion emulator running on Android 7.0. However when I go to **Android Settings**, only up to API Level 22 (i.e Android 5.1) is listed under **Platform Version**.

[image: Appium - Android Settings screenshot]

Just for kicks, I tried to selecting API 22 and launching the inspector but I get the following error:

> [AndroidDriver] Error: Unable to find an active device or emulator
>   with OS 5.1. The following are available: 192.168.56.101:5555 (7.0)
>       at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
>       at Object.callee$0$0$ (lib/android-helpers.js:154:16)
>       at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
>   (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
>       at run (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
>       at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
>       at flush (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)  [Error: Unable to find an active device or emulator with OS 5.1. The
>   following are available: 192.168.56.101:5555 (7.0)]
>
> [debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
>
> [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to
>   find an active device or emulator with OS 5.1. The following are
>   available: 192.168.56.101:5555 (7.0)
>       at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
>       at Object.callee$0$0$ (lib/android-helpers.js:154:16)
>       at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
>   (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
>       at run (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
>       at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
>       at flush (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>
> [AndroidDriver] Cannot shut down Android driver; it has already shut
>   down

I'm running Appium 1.5.3 on macOS Sierra (10.12.1) by the way and I've also set the path to the Android SDK which has the SDK for API 24 installed in the **Advanced** tab.

Is there any way I could include API 24 to this list?

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a very old version of Appium Desktop. I'd suggest you upgrade to the latest, which allows you to manually enter your desired version.

[image: Latest UI]